# Is it possible (and if so where can I find one) to buy a sidereal wall clock or kitchen clock?

Tags: time

I've done some research and can't find one of these anywhere but would be dumbfounded if they didn't exist, surely sidereal wall clocks are sold somewhere (preferably online)?

Comment: Buy a regular pendulum clock and then shorten the pendulum by 0.56%

Comment: A quick Google search turned out this website: https://brgprecision-com.3dcartstores.com/Sidereal-Clocks_c_37.html

Comment: Wow. Those clocks aren't cheap. If you can do electronics, you could probably build one using Arduino or Raspberry Pi for a fraction of those prices.

Comment: I know Willmann-Bell used to sell a kit, you might try to find an old one.  There were some other kits available too.  All of them were digital, and could be done quite trivially with any computer and display today.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question is Off-Topic